# how to add the one pair key and value by using array_merge()?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of
`$data = Array ( [city] => Kabanga [address] => Village ) Array ( [city] => Kahama [address] => Town )` and my goal is to add `array('userId'=>10)` to each inside of the main array.

I have tried

```
 $temp = array();
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                        $temp = array_merge(array('userId' => 10), $data[$i]);
    
                    }
```

so that my goal is to achieve

```
`Array
(
[userId] => 10
[city] => Kabanga
[address] => Village
)
Array
(
[userId] => 10
[city] => Kahama
[address] => Town
)`
```

but it doesn't work. what am I missing please?

Comment: Missing brackets on the `$temp` assignment, ie `$temp[] = array_merge...`. This will append to the `$temp` array instead of resetting its value. See https://3v4l.org/eRkK1

Answer (score 2):

Using **PHP 8.1** [array unpacking feature](https://www.php.net/releases/8.1/en.php#array_unpacking_support_for_string_keyed_arrays)

```php
    $data = [
        [ 'city' => 'Kabanga', 'address' => 'Village' ],
        [ 'city' => 'Kahama', 'address' => 'Town' ]
    ];
    
    $result = array_map(static fn($item) => [ 'userId' => 10, ...$item ], $data);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in PHP < 8.1 due to the array keys being strings.